# Are these graphics card standoffs?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, case, case-mods

I am preparing to build a custom case for myself and have come across these circular holes in my graphics card that look like standoffs holes.
[image]
Could I put standoffs in these to hold the graphics card in place? What are these for? The card is an MSI Radeon R7 370.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like mounting holes for manufacturing purposes - Probably safe to use standoffs, although I would use plastic ones.

Comment: They are not standoff holes.  They likely are mounting holds for ethics-party cooling solutions.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas thank you, non conductive standoffs are a good idea.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you, but I could still use them to hold the graphics card in place right?

Comment: 'ethics party'?

Comment: @Phoenix Nope you can't, just install the card normally, perfectly secure that way

Comment: I'm creating a case that will have it parallel to the motherboard with a riser cable, so I can't do that

Comment: @Ramhound Of course he can use them to secure the card. They might not be designed for that, but it's not an impossibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. No matter how large your card is it should entirely be supported by the screws at the PCIe slot openings at the rear and the PCI slot itself.

There's nothing to screw a standoff to at all *to* anything in a standard case and these would not be used at all. and it might actually be potentially damaging to the card, placing lateral stresses across the video card or causing it to bow done the wrong way. You may end up cracking a PCB or popping out a heatsink.

As for these additional plated screws, there's no logical consumer facing use for them. In theory you may be able to mount a third party, compatible cooler on it, but your mileage/compatibility may vary, and there's no guarantee those holes are at the right place for it, and it would very likely void your warranty.

You really do want to install the card in as standard a way as possible for best results. I suppose you could *support* the card at these points and use *loose* screws, but excessive tightening at these points may end up being bad.